# Group Policy does not open in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, group-policy

gpedit.msc in run or search does not opens group policy editor. Instead it shows an error message that it cannot find 'gpedit.msc'

Comment: Do you mean Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro? Group policy editor is not included in Windows 8, I think.

Comment: Your version of Windows cannot run this command

Comment: @DavidMarshall post this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Group Policy is only for Windows 8 Pro And Enterprise !

Answer (score 0):

The Group Policy Editor is only included in Windows 8 Pro and Windows 8 Enterprise. Many of the group policies are implemented through Registry settings. A [spreadsheet](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250) of these can be downloaded from Microsoft. You can then use Regedit to get the same effect.

I was surprised to find that it is also included in Windows RT on my Surface.